# Merging colors between points

Tags: javascript, google-maps, colors, blending

I have a web application with several points placed on a map. Every point is associated with a value, good values are green,ok values yellow and bad values red. If two values are close enough I would like them to merge colours between them e.g. One point is red and the other point is yellow the area between them should be orange.

I have looked into heat maps but not found anything that works for my needs.

Anyone know of any good libraries that solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just make the images for these points being PNGs with alpha channels set to 0.5 or other suitable value.

Comment: Overlaid images may not necessarily produce expected output; depending on how they're rendered, whichever one's on top will have a stronger effect on the result. (i.e. putting the red on top may result in something 2 parts red and 1 part yellow)